# Virtual Box Guru Meditation Error on starting Windows 10 in already Visualised Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am messing around with my computer and Virtual box, I am running Windows 10 and have Visualised Windows 10, then on the guest machine I installed Virtual box and tried to run Windows 10 but then it the outer guest crashed giving a Guru Meditation Error.

Logs:
[Outer Guest](https://www.mediafire.com/file/7dac3o5ie9rkq2c/Outer_Guest_Log.zip/file)
[Inner Guest](https://www.mediafire.com/file/gchdil6qw06x10h/Inner_Guest_Logs.zip/file)

[Outer Guest Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCUCw.png)
[Inner Guest Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMAa8.png)

Comment: Virtual Box must be installed on the Host machine (not Guest machine) and then the Windows 10 license for the Guest must be a separate license.

Comment: @john Virtual Box is on the host machine and the guest machine, the guest machine is unactivated and the host machine is.

Comment: You have enabled nested virtualization within the VirtualBox configuration on both the host and guest?  Please submit screenshots of the configuration menus in question so the community can verify your settings.

Comment: Also show us any pings you can from the guest and make sure Virtual Box Network setup for the guest is correct

Comment: @Ramhound Read next because of limit to notify

Comment: @John I have added Screenshots of the settings but I was unable to find the Pings, on the Inner Guest settings VT-x/AMD-V was greyed out and unchecked and Nested Paging was also greyed out, could this be because I am unable to turn on Visualisation in the BIOS settings of the Outer Guest.

Comment: Network settings are NAT and should work.  You wrote "could this be because I am unable to turn on Visualisation in the BIOS settings of the Outer Guest."   Yes.  If you cannot set VT-x in BIOS, then you can only run 32-bit guest machines.

Comment: @Stemboy4002 - You did not provide the settings I asked for, I wanted to see if you had enabled nested virtualization, what you provided does not provide the information I was looking for.

Comment: @Ramhiund Sorry I could not find it before and I thought you meant Nested Paging, Nested Virtualisation is greyed out.